# microsoft visual studio 2008 builds keep failing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

My builds keep failing with the following error

```
Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 31 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe'.
```

I find that i have to kill some process called mspdbsrv.exe **description:"microsoft program database"** Then rebuild the entire project. This is annoying. Is there a permanent solution to this problem or is it stuck with me for good?

PS
OS: windows 7 ultimate

msv studio 2008 + sp1 professional

Comment: I encounter the same problem, except that I do not need to do a complete rebuild, just the link.  So, for me it is not worthwhile to arrange to kill the process every time.

Comment: I have tried to kill the process mspdbsrv.exe and then build or rebuild - but I still receive the same error.  Any idea what can be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that for some reason, your `mspdbsrv.exe` is staying alive after the build.  This is what's used to generate your `.pdb` files as part of the build.  The only reliable solution seems to be to kill that process.

What you can do is at least automate that, just add a [post-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) and console kill it.  I'd suggest using the [SysInternals PSKill utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) (free) like this in your post-build:

```
pskill mspdbsrv.exe
```

Comment: It was indeed staying alive.  Killed it.  Then I got `fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23) '(0x000006BA)'`.  Rebooted.  The original problem returned.  Argh.

Comment: `taskkill /IM mspdbsrv.exe /f` in Windows cmd also works for me

Answer (score 2):

This issue came into effect on our Windows10 build slave over the holiday. It worked Thu and failed Fri without any code changes or anyone even in the office either day.  We assume that there was an automated microsoft update that caused the issue.

Disabling **Windows Defender** solved the problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Security Essentials appears to have caused my problem. I added mt.exe to the Excluded processes, and the problem stopped occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved after VIPRE Anti virus disabling.