# Embedding manifest error in visual studio build

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When building C++ programs with VS2008 I occasionally get the following error message

```
1>Linking...
1>Embedding manifest...
1>Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 31 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe'.
```

Restarting the build is almost always successful, so it is a mere nuisance.

I am curious as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

See the earlier question on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486963/microsoft-visual-studio-2008-builds-keep-failing).